# How to continue through loop despite of write.table error?

Tags: r

In R I have a code that runs a loop over a list of search words that are downloaded from a website.  Each search word is then saved as a csv file:

```
...some code...
x <- try(read.table(text=res, sep=",", col.names=c("Week", "TrendsCount"), skip=31, nrows=515))

for(i in 1:iterations){
...some code...
filename <- paste(wordlist[i], "csv", sep = ".")
write.table(x, file = filename, sep = ";", col.names = NA, qmethod = "double")  
}
```

Sometimes the list will contain a search word that returns an error when code is executed, because the word does not exist on the website. This stops the loop. How can I make the loop skip the `write.table` part and just continue with the next word in the list?

Comment: `if (x is found) write table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put write.table in

```
try(..., silent=T)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot andrei and @rawr :). However, the syntax I used was `try(...), silent=T)`, so for others who might have the same problem, remember the extra parenthesis.

Comment: @Sunv No, `try(...), silent=T)` is a syntax error. Parentheses must match.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I meant `try((...), silent=T)`. Thanks @Roland